# connection to SQL database with Office script

Tags: excel, office-scripts

is it possible to make a connection between Office 365 to SQL database using Office scripts? something simillar to `ADODB.Connection` in Excel VBA

Answer (score 2):

You can't connect directly to a database using Office Scripts. You can still get data from a database but the process would need to be a bit different:

1. Instead of querying a database directly, the data would need to be returned to some API (e.g. as JSON)
2. Instead of providing a username / password to connect to the database, you'd use an API key.
3. Once you had access to an API and provided an API key, you could use `fetch` to get the JSON and work with the data in Office Scripts.

You can read more about using fetch with Office Scripts [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/external-fetch-calls)

In addition to this type of process, you could also trying using something like PowerAutomate to query the database directly.